# How can a vector field act on a Lie Algebra element?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, vector-fields, tangent-bundle, tangent-spaces

We have the definition of a vector field as a smooth section of the tangent bundle $$X:P\longrightarrow TP,$$ where $(TP,\pi',P)$ is the tangent bundle over the total space of the principal G-bundle $(P,\pi,M)$. I.e, a vector field is an assignment of a vector ($\in TP$) to every point of a smooth manifold $P$.

I have, however, come across expressions like "$X(A)$" where $X$ is (supposedly) a vector field and $A$ is a Lie algebra element (for example at 19:31 here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j36o4DLLK2k).

How is the vector field defined in this case? Do we simply take for granted that the lie algebra is given a manifold structure, at which point the vector field is defined in the same way, something like $X:T_eG\longrightarrow T(T_eG)$ - assigning a vector in $T(T_eG) $ to another vector in $T_eG$?

Comment: Please add more description of $X(A)$ that you have seen in the lecture.

Comment: Sure, $X\in \Gamma (TP)$ and $A\in T_eG$, where G is the Lie group that acts on the principal G-bundle. We have a map $i:T_eG \longrightarrow \Gamma (TP)$, which takes $A \mapsto X^A $, with $X^A$ being a vector field which is associated to the Lie algebra element $A$ (in what sense the two are "associated" I am unsure). In the lecture, it is stated that $X^A(B)-X^B(A)=0$, which is what I'm trying to understand by first trying to work out how the $X^A$ is defined. My apologies if this is still unclear - I haven't got a great grasp of this material and so it's pretty unclear to me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fundamental vector field generated by $A\in T_eG$. For $u\in P$, this is defined by $X^A(u):=\tfrac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}u\cdot exp(tA)$. Here the dot denotes the principal right action of $G$ on $P$, whose orbits are the fibers of $P$. For each $u\in P$, mapping $A$ to $X^A(u)$ induces a linear isomorphism from $T_eG$ to the vertical subspace $\ker(T_u\pi)\subset T_uP$. So these are the vectors tangent to the fibers of $P$.

Comment: So then once we have the tangent vector $X^A(u)$ (to my understanding $X^A$ is the vector field and evaluating it at $u$ gives you a tangent vector in $T_uP$), how is its action on a Lie algebra element defined? Aren't tangent vectors in essence a "directional derivative", and thus can only act on functions?

Comment: There is no action on a Lie algebra element, this is just a specific class of vector fields that are available on any principal bundle. What occurs in the lecture is the action of a vector field on a function with values in the Lie algebra. (This is just defined component-wise with resprect to any basis of $\mathfrak g$.) In the lecture this is $X^A(\omega(X^B))$. Now $\omega(X^B)$ is the constant function $B$, and writing $X^A(B)$ is just a formality here. In any case, if you differentiate a constant, you get $0$.

Comment: $\omega:\Gamma(TP)\longrightarrow T_eG$ is a Lie algebra valued one-form. Thus, for $X^B\in \Gamma(TP)$, $\omega(X^B)\in T_eG$ right? How do you go from interpreting $\omega(X^B)$ as a Lie algebra element to interpreting it as a Lie-algebra-valued function? Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: In general, if you insert a vector field into a Lie algebra valued one-form, you get a Lie algebra-valued smooth function. I just happens that for fundamental vector fields, this function is constant. This is completely parallel to ordinatry one-fomrs for which $T_eG$ is replaced by $\mathbb R$ or for one-forms with values in some finite dimensional vector space $V$.

Comment: But regardless of whether $X$ is a fundamental vector field, given $\omega(X)$ is a Lie algebra element, it's a vector like any other, and to my understanding this means it acts on functions. Some function $f\in C^\infty (M)$ takes points in the manifold $M$ and returns some real number. How can a vector also be interpreted as a smooth function?

Comment: $\omega(X)$ is a function $P\to T_eG$ and vector fields act on functions with values in any finite dimensional vector space (by expaninging into any basis, differentiating the corresponding real values functions and adding back up).

Comment: Ah, so we are interpreting the Lie algebra as a tangent vector space whose elements are functions, rather than a vector space whose elements are the traditional "directional derivative" notion of a tangent vector?

Comment: No, recall what happens for ordinary forms on a manifold $M$: A one-form $\alpha$ associates to each point $x$ a linear map $\alpha(x):T_xM\to\mathbb R$. For a vector field $\xi$, you define $\alpha(\xi):M\to \mathbb R$ by $\alpha(\xi)(x):=\alpha(x)(\xi(x))$ and this is a smooth function $M\to \mathbb R$ which can be differentiated by another vector field. You can do precsisely the same replacing $\mathbb R$ by a vector space $V$ and hence also by the vector space $T_eG$. No interpretation of $T_eG$ is needed.

Comment: Right, thanks. I've tried to summarise what I (think I) understand from all your help in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I've got so far. We have an ordinary one-form $\tilde{\theta}:P\longrightarrow T^*P$, and thus for $p\in P$ we have $\tilde{\theta}(p):T_pP\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with  $X_p\mapsto\tilde{\theta}(p)(X_p)$. An equivalent definition is
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 \theta:\Gamma(TP)&\longrightarrow C^{\infty}(P) \\
 X&\longmapsto \theta(X)
\end{alignat*}
where
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 \theta(X):P&\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
 p&\longmapsto \theta(X)(p):=\tilde{\theta}(p)(X_p).
\end{alignat*}

We can think of $\mathbb{R}$ as having some vector space structure, so everywhere we see it we can replace it by the Lie algebra, and produce a Lie-algebra valued one-form via $\tilde{\omega}:P\longrightarrow T^*P$, and thus for $p\in P$ we have $\tilde{\omega}(p):T_pP\longrightarrow T_eG$ with  $X_p\mapsto\tilde{\omega}(p)(X_p)$. We therefore have
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 \omega:\Gamma(TP)&\longrightarrow T_eG \\
 X&\longmapsto \omega(X)
\end{alignat*}
where
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 \omega(X):P&\longrightarrow T_eG \\
 p&\longmapsto \omega(X)(p):=\tilde{\omega}(p)(X_p).
\end{alignat*}

Thus, $\omega$ is a Lie-algebra valued one-form and $\omega(X)$ is a Lie-algebra-valued function, and can be differentiated by plugging it into a vector field.

Is that right?